# Is the a way to internally monitor the transition to the first state in an Akka FSM?

Tags: scala, akka

Considering an FSM actor that starts at state Idle

```
startWith(Idle, IdleData)
```

I'd like to monitor the transition to this first state (from no state?)

I tried

```
onTransition {
    case _ -> Idle => // Wasn't called
}
```

According to the relevant [FSM](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html#Internal_Monitoring) documentation:

> It is also possible to pass a function object accepting two states to
>   onTransition, in case your transition handling logic is implemented as
>   a method:

```
onTransition(handler _)

def handler(from: StateType, to: StateType) {
  // handle it here ...
}
```

Given that the from type is StateType and not Option[StateType] I think that it may not be possible, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something similar recently.

If I understand your question correctly, Here is one way to monitor when you start off your FSM from the initial state:

```
class ExampleFSM extends Actor with FSM[State, Data] {
  // A FSM begins its existence in Idle state and can move to different states
  startWith(Idle, NoData)

  when(Idle) {
    case Event(SetData(something), NoData) =>
      goto(SomeOtherState) using Data(something)
  }

  onTransition {
    case Idle -> Idle =>
      stateData match {
        case _ =>
          println("Initial transition")
      }
  }
}
```

In the above example, When We instantiate the FSM pass-in the message `SetData(something)`, It starts at the state `Idle` and there is a transition that you can monitor which is `Idle -> Idle`.

In the above case when we start the FSM we can see an output `Initial transition` printed, you can leverage this to do more complex stuff as per your needs

So basically if you update your existing transition from `case _ => Idle` to `case Idle -> Idle` it should work

Note: There might be more than one way to do this, I am also still exploring the power of Akka FSM so my answer is just having one possible way of getting this.