# Akka FSM Testkit doesn't catch *starting state* correctly

Tags: akka, akka-testkit, akka-fsm

I am using Akka FSM to simulate a moving elevator (you are going: not again! :-)) and trying to test the FSM using regular Testkit features, but there seems to be a gap either in my understanding or the published behaviour of FSM (or both).

Here's the relevant portion of the code:

```
class LiftCarriageWithMovingState (val movingStateSimulator: ActorRef) extends Actor
  with LoggingFSM[LiftState,LiftData]
  with ActorLogging
{
  val mxTimeToWaitStopping = 250 milliseconds
  private var pendingPassengerRequests: Vector[NextStop] = Vector.empty
  private var currentFloorID = 0 // Always start at Ground Floor

  val timeToReachNextFloor = 1000 millis  // up  or down, same time taken

  private val dontCare: StateFunction = {
    // ..
  }

  private val powerYourselfOff: StateFunction = {
    case Event(InstructedToPowerOff,_) =>
      stay
  }

  private val powerYourselfOn: StateFunction = {
    case Event(InstructedToPowerOn,_)  =>
      goto (PoweredOn)
  }

  private val beReady: StateFunction = {
    case Event(BeReady,_)          =>
      settleDownAtGroundFloor
      goto (Ready)
  }

  // .. other StateFunctions here

  startWith(PoweredOff,InitialData)

  when (PoweredOff) (powerYourselfOn orElse
                     dontCare)

  when (PoweredOn)  (powerYourselfOff orElse
                     beReady orElse
                     dontCare
  // ...
```

One expects that the FSM will respond with the CurrentState message, just after it is created and *startWith* function is called, but that doesn't happen. This test (partial code again) fails:

```
"A LiftCarriage" must {
    "be ready, when it settles down after being PoweredOn" in {

      val testCarriageFSM = TestFSMRef(new LiftCarriageWithMovingState(movingStateSimulator))

      expectMsgPF() {
        case CurrentState(_,PoweredOff) => true // Line 46, see the stacktrace below
      }
```

thus:

```
 A LiftCarriage
[info] - must be ready, when it settles down after being PoweredOn *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg:
[info]   at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
[info]   at akka.testkit.TestKitBase$class.expectMsgPF(TestKit.scala:356)
[info]   at akka.testkit.TestKit.expectMsgPF(TestKit.scala:718)
[info]   at withExplicitMovingState.LiftCarriageMovingStoppingCorrectlyTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiftCarriageMovingStoppingCorrectlyTest.scala:46)
[info]   at withExplicitMovingState.LiftCarriageMovingStoppingCorrectlyTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiftCarriageMovingStoppingCorrectlyTest.scala:42)
[info]   at withExplicitMovingState.LiftCarriageMovingStoppingCorrectlyTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiftCarriageMovingStoppingCorrectlyTest.scala:42)
```

Is there a gap in my understanding? Please educate me, if so.

I also see that exactly the same question - asked in more summarised form [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33311614/is-the-a-way-to-internally-monitor-the-transition-to-the-first-state-in-an-akka) - has gone unanswered. Isn't this seen to be a gap in the semantics of Akka FSM and Testkit, **worth addressing**? :-P